# Shrinkwrap moving below the surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, customization, shrinkwrap

I am trying to use the Shrinkwrap modifier to wrap clothes around my model but some of the clothing is moving below the surface on some of my model. If I use a negative value for the shrinkwrap the parts that were outside my mesh are inside and the parts that were inside are outside.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you most likely have flipped normals on some of your model (the arm). The Shrinkwrap is set to move the cloth above the closest surface. For the arm the normal is pointing “inside” so “above” is effectively inside your model.